# PostgreSQL: не найдены отношения

Tags: postgresql, psql

(debian 9.5.0, psql 9.6.17) работал с базой данных, взятой с сайта postgrepro.ru версии 2017 г. К сожалению, возникали в ходе выполнения запросов проблемы, связанные с отображением данных. Решил скачать с того же сайта более старую версию (2016 г.). Перед скачиванием в терминале я удалил б.д. версии 17-го года. Однако когда скачал уже версию 2016 г., у меня снова возникли проблемы.

```
 demo=# \dn
    Список схем
  Имя   | Владелец 
--------+----------
 public | postgres
(1 строка)

demo=# \d
Отношения не найдены.
postgres=# \c demo
Вы подключены к базе данных "demo" как пользователь "postgres".
demo=# set search_path to bookings;
SET
demo=# \d
Отношения не найдены.
demo=# select * from aircrafts;
ОШИБКА:  отношение "aircrafts" не существует
```

Не понимаю, в чём заключается проблема. Почему у меня "отношения не найдены". В самой б.д. все таблицы с данными есть (в текстовом редакторе открыл и нашёл их). Может отсутствия отношений как-то связано с удалением старой версии или я неправильно распаковал б.д.? (Скачал, распаковал в текстовом редакторе и сохранил, а затем подключился к ней в терминале) Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Ну, это всего лишь значит, что таблиц в базе нет.  Добавьте **в вопрос,** почему вы считаете, что отношения там должны быть.

Comment: Хорошо, добавил

Comment: `psql 9.7.17` - такой версии не существует. Добавьте в вопрос почему вы считаете что у вас в базе под названием `postgres` есть объекты в схеме bookings? Начните с проверки в `\dn` есть ли такая схема вообще в это базе.

Comment: хорошо, добавил. Версия 9.6.17 (моя ошибочка)

Comment: у вас вовсе нет схемы bookings. Откуда бы тогда там быть таблицам?

Comment: Как вы это поняли? Можете объяснить? Просто таблицы ведь должны быть, раз все данные я смог увидеть, развернув скаченную базу в текстовом редакторе.